# How to get and show data from different models in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have 3 tables: `orders`, `discounts` and `products` in the way that `product` has many `discounts` (discount times). `Discount` has many `orders`. in other words, it looks like: `Product > Discount > Order.`

How can I get all data from 3 table, put it into one order view (do it in `Order` controller) and show it out (in `Order` view).

That's what I did, but It didnt work:

```
//Order controller
public function index() {
    $this->Order->recursive=1;
    $this->set('orders', $this->Order->find('all'));
}


// Order view
<?php foreach ($orders as $order): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $order ['Order']['order_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($order['Product']['product_name'], array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'view', $order['Product']['product_id'])); ?></td>     //I showed it here
            <td><?php echo $order['Order']['order_date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $order['Order']['payment']; ?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($order); ?>
```

Please help me! thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the result of `debug($this->Order->find('all'))`pls?

Comment: Use containable to fetch deep relations.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention that you are in Order controller you can do any of these:

```
$this->Order->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$orders = $this->Order->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('Discount' => 'Product')));
$this->set(compact('orders'));
```

Now, in your view you can iterate over $orders variable.

PS: Of course, I am assuming here that Discount Belongs to Product.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It showed an error: Error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object. Also, what do I have to do to get data of 2 table Order and Product in Discount controller?

Comment: What CakePHP version are you using? did you put that code in OrdersController?

Comment: Im using 2.3. But I think I found the problem.

Comment: Would you share the problem?

Comment: oh, one of my project member just added some stuffs that I didnt know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easy way and different functionality

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('datas',
        $this->Order->find('all',
            array (
                'conditions'    => array('Site_id' => $site_name),
                'fields'        => array('Date_time','Ac_1_Status','Tempin'),
                'order'         => array('id' => 'desc'),
                'limit'         => 200
             )
        )
    );
}
```